# Bypass publish approval on content creation for a certain role

Tags: users

I have a content type *"place"* which can be created by any registered user but needs to be published by a *"site editor"* role. I also have a *"place editor"* role which will have his *"place"* content published as soon as it is created, not needing an approval.

There are other content types such as *"event"*, which will have their own editors, so that a *"place editor"* will have to have his *"event"* content published by a site editor, but his *"place"* content will be published right away.

Can you name a module for this? I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could user [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to publish or unpublish content based on a role or any other condition.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you might need a module to moderate content (especially if the content may be changed after publishing and these changes need to get approved again before being published).

In Drupal 6, you might want to try [content_moderation](http://drupal.org/project/content_moderation) or [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning).

In Drupal 7, [workbench_moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) would be my first choice.